# How to get a folder name from first letter

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm attempting to update from my device that I have created, my system is running on linux, and what I'm attempting to do is an automatic update when the folder is inside the path. So for example, whenever I have the folder with the name "1.1.9.19" or "1.1.2.1" I will get this name and store it into a variable, after that, I will get my current software version, so for example, the current software is"1.1.8" since it is diferent, the update will occur, if it was equal it won't occur. I'm having problems getting the folder name, since I won't know the folder name all the time, the only certain is that the first letter is 1. 
[image]

Getting the software:

```
SfCurrentVersion = getSoftwareVersion.replace(".", "")) # returns 1.1.8 after replace 118

folderName = "1.1.9.19"

if SfCurrentVersion <= folderName.replace(".",""):
    print('Already up to date...')
else:
    print("Update start...")
    subprocess.run(update.process)
    print("Update finished")
```

How can I get the folder name, knowing only that the first letter is always "1"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import os

# 1. using a generator:
folder_name = next(filter(lambda x: x.startswith('1'), os.listdir()))

# 2. try and catch with generator
try:
    folder_name = next(filter(lambda x: x.startswith('1'), os.listdir()))
except StopIteration:
    folder_name = None

# 3. or first list item:
folder_name = list(filter(lambda x: x.startswith('1'), os.listdir()))[0]
```

Comment: Just a question, whenever there is not a folder, I get an StopIteration, which stops my code, why is that?

Comment: That is because it is a generator. You could also use `list` and get the first items. But then if there is no folder you get the `IndexError`. So the `StopIteration` is the equivalent of the IndexError for lists and states that the object is empty